# SignalR C# AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

я делаю чат на SignalR и у меня идет подключения к хабу при переходе на определенную страницу. и при выходе с этой страницы или переходе в другую у меня поключение сбрасывается. как сделать так чтобы подключение к хабу держалось постоянно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Используйте ajax запросы, чтобы обновлять страницу вместо полной ее перезагрузки.

Comment: нет. мне необходимо чтобы он держал соединение. короче идея такая чтобы я пользователь мог получить уведомление что на ему пришло сообщение когда он находится на другой странице. как сделать?

Comment: Я же вам сказал, как, а вы не разбираясь в вопросе мне отвечаете словом "нет". Используйте AJAX запросы для обновления содержимого страницы вместо ее полной перезагрузки. Оставить соединение открытым при полной перезагрузке страницы технически невозможно. Когда пользователь покидает страницу, браузер рвет все установленные текущей страницей соединения, так устроен веб.

Comment: Если вам необходимо открывать соединение с хабом на другой странице (не странице с чатом), то подключайте там signalr и подписывайтесь на событие получения уведомлений. Но правильней все таки будет сделать ajax как сказал @aepot. Ещё вариант, использовать один layout для всех страниц и в нем подключаться к хабу. Так на любой странице вы все будете подключены.